# does searchable plugin work only with hibernate?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, searchable, searchable-plugin

I use grails-1.3.2 and hbase-0.2.4 plugin.

I want to use searchable plugin,
but when I install plugin with it appears hibernate plugin,
which conflicts with hbase-0.2.4 plugin.

When I am uninstalling hibernate plugin, I can not run my application 
and get this message:

Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [searchable]
- Plugin: searchable, Dependencies: [dataSource, domainClass, i18n, core, hibernate]

My questions are:

Does searchable plugin work only with hibernate plugin?

If no, how I have to configure it for hbase plugin?

**Who know what searchable like plugin is there for hbase ?????**

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Searchable uses Compass which is tightly coupled with Hibernate. It adds Hibernate event listeners to detect when a new instance is saved/edited/deleted/etc. and uses that information to update the Lucene index. In order for the plugin to work with another persistence library or NoSQL database there would need to be the same event information available and in general that's rarely even close to being there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Searchable plugin works only with Hibernate. I have asked the same question on Grails user group when I was looking to put searchable and mongo DB to work. 
The searchable plugin depends on Hibernate os it can't work without it. HBase may sufficiently be scaled for complex searches.
Please follow this [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Searchable-plugin-and-mangoDB-td3340974.html)  for more details

Comment: thank you very much...do you know searchable like plugin, which will work for hbase?                                  does Elastic search plugin work for mongo DB?

Comment: I have seen this .. I used native mongo search capabilities. If you want to put the elastic search you have to change the source code of the plugin your self. May be you can ask Stephane (on Grails user) if elastics search was implemented or not yet.
I have this example http://blog.jayway.com/2010/11/14/full-text-search-with-mongodb-and-lucene-analyzers/

Comment: it seems i can not use searchable plugin...it does not work for my grails version..

Comment: Yes .. You have maybe to think of using elastic could API directly without plugin if you really need to use lucene with hbase